# Set JRebel as default Maven executor in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

I am using IntelliJ on Ubuntu and I am trying to find a way to set JRebel as default executor, right now using IntelliJ, double-clicking a Maven build on the pane will run the default Jave runtime, what can be done to set a specific runtime, in this case JRebel. So when I double-click on "clean", "package" -- and most importantly the actual build to run the app it will use JRebel executor.

We can always run each build to use specific executor, but you have to explicitly right-click then select it, but is there a way to make it the default one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I wasn't able to find a way to switch the default executor to JRebel, an alternative would be to add JRebel agent as a VM argument for the default executor. You can do that by editing the *run configurations* for your maven executor and under *Runner* tab specifying a following VM argument:

```
-agentpath:/path/to/lib/libjrebel64.so
```

This way, application will be ran with JRebel even when running with the default executor.

Comment: Thanks Risto, are you from JRebel team?

Comment: Yes I am, so if you have any further questions, let us know.